# How do I strip the leading u on each item in a list?

Tags: python, list, strip

My list contains a number of stock symbols but for some reason everyone has a leading u. I was wondering how I could strip the u away? This is the list

[u'GOLD', u'AEM', u'CDE', u'CLF', u'FOE', u'HL', u'LPX', u'MAS', u'NEM', u'NUE', u'OLN', u'PPG', u'MUX', u'WY', u'X', u'KGC', u'AKS', u'ALB', u'PAAS', u'FCX', u'CCJ', u'CENX', u'SSRM', u'STLD', u'TREX', u'IAG', u'EGO', u'TRQ', u'AUY', u'NG', u'SA', u'HUN', u'NGD', u'WPM', u'CF', u'TECK', u'LYB', u'TROX', u'AG', u'MOS', u'FSM', u'PVG', u'SLCA', u'SAND', u'AGI', u'CSTM', u'BTG', u'ESI', u'AXTA', u'SUM', u'UNVR', u'CC', u'AA', u'KL', u'DWDP', u'NTR']

Comment: Which version of Python are you using? Why do you want to strip them? The `u` is a unicode prefix for a [string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals).  Try `str(u'GOLD')`.

Comment: Switch to Python 3.

Comment: https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The u means that the strings in the list are in unicode format.

You can convert them using the str on each:

```
map(str, list)
```